# Trouble Reading a Text File with Visual Studio in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, visual-studio-2015, fstream

I can not get Visual Studio to read in a text file.  Below is the code I have.  The file opens perfectly in a Unix Environment, but it does not work when copied and pasted into Visual Studio.  I am using fstream to open the file. Why the file is not being read?

When I run the program, it builds but I get no output. I have an output statement `cout << "inf\n"`.  So the loop is not even being reached, which is why I believe the file is not being read.  Again, when I run the same code in a Unix environment the output statement does display and the values from the file are displayed ( via tree.insert(), tree.remove() ).

I tried the solution in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017847/c-trouble-reading-a-text-file). As it suggested, I changed my working directory to $(ProjectDir)\Debug and $(ProjectDir)\Release. Also, I moved my text file from the Resources folder to my Source Folder in the Solution Explorer. However, the file still was not being read.

I also updated my code to include `cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno);` directly after fstream inf ("BTREE5_1.txt").  With this line of code the output I get is

`Error: No such file or directory`

Can someone please explain why? My text files are in the same folder as my code as explained above.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>  
#include <cstdio>
#include "BTree.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
bool first = true;

BTree tree(6, 2);
int value;
char s[80], command;

ifstream inf("BTree5_1.txt");
cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno);


inf.getline(s, 80);

while (inf >> command >> value)
{
    cout << "inf\n";
    if (command == 'i')
        tree.insert(value);
    else
    {
        if (first)
        {
            cout << "After all insertions.\n";
            tree.print();
            first = false;
        } // if first

        cout << "Deleting " << value << ". \n";
        tree.remove(value);
        tree.print();
        // fgets(s, 80, stdin);
    } // else deletion
} // while
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}  // main
```

Comment: What happens when you run the program?

Comment: "trouble" and "does not work" are the opposite of descriptive. What *actually* goes wrong? What output do you get, if any? Can you include an example of the text file that isn't working?

Comment: Kindly check the error code using 'strerror(errno);'. Most probably the file path issue. Alternatively you can validate the same by providing complete path instead of relative.

Comment: Can you explain how I would check the error code?

Comment: Please check following link for the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337602/how-to-get-error-message-when-ifstream-open-fails

Comment: I have edited my post to give a description about what happens when I run the program.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Using stderror(erno) right after ifstream inf("BTree5_1.txt"), I get "Error: No such file or directory.."  Can someone please explain why?  As explained in the post, I moved my text file from the Resources Folder to the Sources Folder in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: right click the project in the solution explorer, select properties. Look at Configuration Properties, Debugging, Working Directory. This will be "cwd" when you run the application in the debugger. Optionally you can just have main print the cwd to double check, or provide the full path to the file. If it says something like "$(ProjectDir)" click the dropdown on the right, click the "Macros>>" button, and see what the actual value of ProjectDir is.

Comment: Did you make sure your files were not "BTree5_1.txt.txt"? I have seen this recently in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935386/c-createfile-does-not-found-txt-file-in-same-folder-as-exe#comment76847095_44935386

Comment: User rights? Non-printable characters in the file name? Try listing the files that exist, try using process monitor, try creating a new file without copy-pasting or transferring it from elsewhere etc.

Comment: Hi Kenny. My project name is p2. Under "Macros>>" my "$(ProjectDir)" is"C:\Users\s.proctor\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ecs60\p2\p2\p2."   Should there be 3 p2's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I copied and pasted my text files from the Unix Environment.  To fix this I just placed the text files into my Directory from my C Drive.

ie>) C:\Users\s.proctor\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ecs60\p2\p2\p2